# undefined reference to unique_int_ptr

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have the following code and I am getting these errors:

```
"/tmp/ccymmVdG.o: In function `main':
1main.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `unique_int_ptr::unique_int_ptr(int*)"
```

unique_int.hpp

```
#ifndef UNIQUE_PTR_HPP_INCLUDED
#define UNIQUE_PTR_HPP_INCLUDED
#include <typeinfo>

template<class Template> class unique_ptr
{
     public:
           unique_ptr(Template* ptr);
          ~ unique_ptr();
          Template* get();
          Template* operator->();
          Template& operator*();
     private:
          Template* m_ptr;
         /* unique_ptr(unique_ptr<Template> const&);
          unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&);*/
};

#endif /* UNIQUE_PTR_HPP_INCLUDED */
```

unique_int_ptr.hpp

```
#ifndef UNIQUE_PTR_INT_HPP_INCLUDED
#define UNIQUE_PTR_INT_HPP_INCLUDED


class unique_int_ptr
{
    public:
        int* get();
        unique_int_ptr (int* data);
        ~unique_int_ptr ();
    private:
        int* m_ptr;
};
#endif //UNIQUE_PTR_INT_HPP_INCLUDED
```

unique_ptr.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unique_ptr.hpp"

template<typename Template> 
unique_ptr<Template>::unique_ptr(Template* ptr)
{
    m_ptr = ptr;
}

template<typename Template> 
unique_ptr<Template>::~unique_ptr()
{
    delete m_ptr;
}

template<typename Template> 
Template* unique_ptr<Template>::get()
{
    return m_ptr;
}

template<typename Template>
Template* unique_ptr<Template>:: operator ->()
{
    return m_ptr;
}

template<typename Template>
Template& unique_ptr<Template>::operator *()
{
    return *m_ptr;
}
```

unique_int_ptr.cpp

```
    #include "unique_int_ptr.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

unique_int_ptr::unique_int_ptr (int* data)
{
    m_ptr = new int;
    m_ptr = data;
}

unique_int_ptr::~unique_int_ptr()
{
    delete m_ptr;
}

int* unique_int_ptr::get ()
{
     return m_ptr;
}
```

1main.cpp

```
#include "unique_ptr.hpp"
#include "unique_int_ptr.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#define TEST_TRUE(x)  printf("Test '%s' %s\n", #x, (x) ? "passed" : "failed!")
struct SimpleData
{
    int first;
    char second;
};
this is my main function 
int main()
{
    {
        int* data = new int(55);    // allocate raw pointer

        // create a managed pointer and let it manage data
        unique_int_ptr data_ptr(data);

        // Make sure that both pointers show the same value
        TEST_TRUE(*data == *data_ptr.get());

        // Both ways
        *(data_ptr.get()) = 99;
       TEST_TRUE(*data == *data_ptr.get());
    };
    {
        int* data = new int(55);    // allocate raw pointer

        // create a managed pointer and let it manage data
        unique_ptr<int> data_ptr(data);

        // Make sure that both pointers show the same value
        TEST_TRUE(*data == *data_ptr.get());

        // Both ways
        *(data_ptr.get()) = 99;
        TEST_TRUE(*data == *data_ptr.get());
    };
    {
        SimpleData* data = new SimpleData;    // allocate raw pointer
        data->first = 55;
        data->second = 'C';

        // create a managed pointer and let it manage data
        unique_ptr<SimpleData> data_ptr(data);

        // Make sure that both pointers show the same value
        TEST_TRUE(data->first == data_ptr->first);
        TEST_TRUE(data->second == data_ptr->second);

        // Both ways
        data_ptr->first = 99;
        data_ptr->second = 'D';
        TEST_TRUE(data->first == data_ptr->first);
        TEST_TRUE(data->second == data_ptr->second);

        unique_ptr<int> int_ptr(new int);
        *int_ptr = 199;


    // both allocations are released here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea why I am getting that error? This error appears several times. I looked at other examples about templates but it does not work.

Comment: You can't put template implementations in cpp files. Just move all template definitions to your header files and it'll work.

Comment: it works thank you very much. But I know some examples against that. Are you sure i can not put template in cpp ?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. Look at the link above your question. There's a very good reason why you can't. You have to read more and understand how linking works in C++ so that you don't do these mistakes, because sometimes they compromise your design.